# Can I use chain rule for 2nd derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If I do have $(x^{4}+10x^{2}+1)^{98}$ and I have to find 2nd derivative of it, can I just simply do that like:

$(f\circ g)''(x) = f''(g(x))*g''(x)$ ?

Comment: No, that's wrong. People  have given formulas for the second derivative, some of which are correct. Instead you should just find the derivative using the chain rule, and then differentiate again using the product rule and the chain rule.

Answer (score 3):

No, since
$$(f\circ g)'=(f'\circ g)g'$$
then differentiating again gives
$$(f\circ g)''=(f''\circ g)g'^2+(f'\circ g)g''.$$

See [Faa di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula) for higher derivatives.

Comment: Just as a note, in addition to Faa di Bruno's formula, higher order chain rules can be more obviously seen using this modified notation for the Leibniz notation for higher order derivatives - https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09553

Answer (score 1):

No. We have $$\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x))=f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$$ so $$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}f(g(x))=f''(g(x))\cdot g'(x) \cdot g'(x)+ f'(g(x))\cdot g''(x)\neq f''(g(x))\cdot g''(x)$$

So in your example, $$f(x)=x^{98}\implies f'(x)=98x^{97}\implies f''(x)=98\cdot97x^{96}$$ and $$g(x)=x^4+10x^2+1\implies g'(x)=4x^3+20x\implies g''(x)=12x^2+20$$ so $$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(x^4+10x^2+1)^{98}=\cdots?$$

Answer (score 1):

The first derivative of $$x\mapsto f(g(x))$$ is (by the chain rule)
$$x\mapsto g'(x)f'(g(x)).$$
So to obtain the derivative of this (i.e., the second derivative of $f\circ g$), you need the product rule and the chain rule
$$ x\mapsto g''(x)f'(g(x)+g'(x)\cdot g'(x)f''(g(x))$$